# Vapor MongoDB Provider Error

Tags: swift, mongodb, vapor

I am trying to run a Vapor app on my local machine and have MongoDb installed and running.

I have this as my mongo.json: `{
  "user": "test",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "reading_journal",
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 2701
}`

which is correct in terms of the info for the local DB.

My main.swift:

```
import Vapor
import FluentMongo
import VaporMongo


let drop = Droplet(providers: [VaporMongo.Provider.self])

drop.get { req in
    let lang = req.headers["Accept-Language"]?.string ?? "en"
    return try drop.view.make("welcome", [
        "message": Node.string(drop.localization[lang, "welcome", "title"])
    ])
}

drop.resource("users", UserController())
drop.resource("posts", PostController())

drop.run()
```

Yet in the log I get: "Could not initialize provider Provider: Socket failed with code 61 ("No data available") [connectFailed] "Unknown error"

Is there some other initialization that needs to be done? This is a brand new MongoDB DB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to add `"host": "0.0.0.0"` in the `mongo.json`

Answer (score 1):

That error usually happens if MongoDB is not running on the correct port. Make sure whatever you have in your `mongo.json` file matches what port MongoDB is running on.

Comment: That wasn't it. I just forgot to add the user preparation to the droplet constructor. Thanks though!